# Pass a value in a secondary activity android

Tags: android, android-activity, static

I created in my Android project another activity. I execute it using this code(this is written in my main activity):

```
activity2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondaryActivity.class);
startActivity(activity2);
```

The problem is that I need to pass a value to the new activity. I've done it creating a `public static` value in the secondary activity. Can I do it in a different way?

Comment: Use `Bundle`, they will help you.

Comment: Remember, static variables are your enemy.

Comment: @Farhan or precisely your memory enemy. :p

Comment: Have you searched before posting this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application/2091482

Comment: No OP has not searched before because if it was then OP won't frame the question.

Comment: Not just memory, when using static variables to hold flags and programming around those flags, managing a piece of code few months down the road becomes a nightmare.

Comment: @jackjay, not only memory. When using the same method from different classes, static variables keep only the last values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Intent extras :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondaryActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("keyName","value");
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in SecondaryActivity's onCreate method, get value like this :

```
String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("keyName");
```

Comment: Now it doesn't allow me to accept the answer, I will do it in 10 min

Comment: Check `getIntent().getExtras() != null`.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```
Intent activity2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondaryActivity.class);
activity2.putExtra("key", "value")
startActivity(activity2);
```

**In SecondaryActivity.class**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //getData using key
    String value = getIntent().getStringExtras("key");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Intent `extras` to pass `value` to your `SecondaryActivity`:

**SEND:**

```
// MainActivity.java

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondaryActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("KEY_VALUE", "Some value");
startActivity(intent);
```

**RECEIVE:**

```
// SecondaryActivity.java

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    .........
    ..................

    String value = "";
    if(getIntent().getExtras() != null)
        value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("KEY_VALUE");

    // Do something with value
}
```